# There was an error in the Mac App Store. Please try again later. (13)

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, error

I have big problem. I can' t install any application from the Mac App Store. I have message "There was an error in the App Store. Please try again later. (13)". I'm search for this bug in google.

Problem started when I uninstall xCode and two others programs(i don't remember names). But i don't have any error message, when i unistall it.

What I tried:
1. Delete appstore cookies
2. Activate Debug mode and click Reset Application in Appstore
3. Do Repair Permision on my disk in disk utitlity program
4. Logout apple ID account, restart system
5. Search for not complete installed apps. No one here.
6. Tried download anything from iTunes. The same error message.

And i still have problem.

I have mac mini. Mac OS X Lion with all updates.

This is what i found on internet. What I can do now ?

Answer (score 6):

I was experiencing the same problem: unable to purchase or update any items from the App Store, with an error code (13).

I came across another thread here - [Cannot Install or Update Apps in App Store - Error 13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22229/cannot-install-or-update-apps-in-) app-store-error-13 - which basically suggests deleting a cookie-preferences file for the App Store. I tried it, and it indeed worked for me.

The steps are:

1) quit the App Store app, if it's open.

2) delete the file, which will be in: ~/Library/Cookies/com.apple.appstore.plist

3) restart the App Store app, and try purchasing or downloading/updating something.

Let us know if this fixes the problem for you! :-)

Comment: I just followed the advice to delete the cookie and it worked!

Comment: @MissOh You should up vote this answer if it helped.

Comment: It didn' t fixed my problem then. I must reinstall system, becouse i tried a lot of solutions at internet and still not worked.

Comment: I am running into same issue. Any luck?

Comment: Removing the cookies worked for me! +1! :)

Comment: At least on Mavericks (10.9.1) this file is called com.apple.appstore.cookies, and it's a directory. So, ensure App Store app is exited; rm -rf ~/Library/Cookies/com.apple.appstore.cookies  start App Store app again, sign out (if deleting the above didn't already log you out) and sign in again. Worked for me when the above didn't...

Comment: This also did not solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled OS, because i don' t have any other ideas.

Comment: Did that resolve the issue?