# App Store opens unDock Lite product page seemingly randomly

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I recently installed [unDock Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/undock-lite/id413897021?mt=12) from the Mac App Store but was not satisfied with its functionality and uninstalled it the same day.

But from time to time the App Store opens the unDock Lite product page.

Is this some very rude advertising from the unDock Lite creators, or could there be a shortcut registered for example, and OS X takes me to the product page associated with it, if it's not currently installed?

Comment: Simple test: if you quick unDock Lite, does it still open the page periodically?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I uninstalled `unDock Lite` already. But why would any company link to the product site if its free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other tips might be useful for some people experiencing similar issues, I have found the reason for this weird behavior.

I had a tab open in Firefox, and every time I restarted Firefox, it opened the shop. I didn't immediately drew a connection between the two, since I have many open tabs, and the timing seemed coincidental, as it took maybe two or three minutes after launching Firefox for the App Store to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any mention of the app or the page in `~/Library/Cookies/com.apple.appstore.plist`? At least [one other AskDifferent user had trouble with this file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/22229/3117) and solved the problem by deleting it - maybe that should be the last resort though.

You can also enable "debug mode" in the Mac App Store by doing `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -boolean YES` - when you have done that you will see a new menu:

[image: Debug Menu]

I would try `Clear Cookies` first, and if that doesn't help, `Reset Application`.

Comment: The cookie file does not appear human readable, except for some bits. Those did not contain any reference to unDock Lite as far as I can tell.